# How does a computer decide whether to use integrated or dedicated graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics

When a computer has both integrated and dedicated graphics, it makes a decision on which one to use for a given program.

- What does it look at in order to make that decision?
- What can the writer of the program do to make sure the correct one is chosen for the given task? (e.g. if the program was a video-game it would want the computer to choose dedicated graphics, if the program was a word-processor it would want the computer to choose integrated)

Edit for Clarification:
In particular, I am talking about windows laptops. The question came to me after I saw my laptop using Intel Integrated graphics for some games when the laptop's dedicated Nvidia graphics are clearly the better choice.

More Clarification:
I know that the drivers control which are used, (on my laptop I can see which is what program is using which graphics in Nvidia control panel). I'm also not wondering how to change what graphics a given program uses. I'm wondering what specific things it's looking at in order to make the decision on what graphics to use.

Comment: What OS are you asking about? Do you have a particular programming framework in mind? Are you asking about laptops (two GPUs with a shared output) or about desktops (each GPU has independent outputs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer doesn't decide. Apps decide, and the default is normally the lower powered GPU (e.g., integrated).

If an app needs higher performance graphics, it can check in the Registry to see if more that one GPU is available, and if so, then it can change to the higher powered GPU. That decision's made by the developers; if they don't need high power, then Windows will continue with the default display adapter.