# How do application programs tell the operating system whether to use GPU or CPU to generate graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, operating-systems, integrated-graphics

We already have this question:

- [How does a computer decide whether to use integrated or dedicated graphics?](https://superuser.com/questions/1512304/how-does-a-computer-decide-whether-to-use-integrated-or-dedicated-graphics)

And [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1512307/167207) is, **the application programs decide**.

> The computer doesn't decide. Apps decide, and the default is normally the lower powered GPU (e.g., integrated).
>
> If an app needs higher performance graphics, it can check in the Registry to see if more that one GPU is available, and if so, then it can change to the higher powered GPU. That decision's made by the developers; if they don't need high power, then Windows will continue with the default display adapter.

But we know that application programs don't have access to hardware; they ask the Operating System to access hardware resources and the OS in turn will do the work under the hood. And if I'm not mistaken, the way applications talk to the OS is by invoking system calls.

So my question is, if a certain application program needs to draw graphics, how does it tell the OS if it should use the GPU or not? Are there a set of system calls that are only for GPU and a set of system calls that are not?

Comment: Are you actually asking about GPU vs CPU, or are you actually asking about integrated GPU vs discrete GPU?

Comment: @u1686_grawity integrated GPU vs discrete GPU. After all, integrated GPU is inside the CPU package, so I just called it "CPU".

Comment: Which really makes it a completely different question, as then it's about GPU rendering vs CPU rendering...

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, at least on Windows and Linux, there is a notion of "device files". There aren't any dedicated syscalls for using a GPU – instead the program opens a device file corresponding to the GPU and interacts with it through the "generic" read/write/mmap/ioctl calls (which the corresponding kernel driver receives). For example, if I remember correctly, `\\.\Display0` on Windows versus `/dev/dri/card0` on Linux (plus `/dev/fb0` for basic 2D).

On Windows NT, these device files exist outside of the regular "filesystem" world – WinObj[Ex] can show you the whole picture – while on Linux they're directly visible within the filesystem.

This means that the OS doesn't specifically distinguish between *two* GPUs – it has a generic mechanism for dealing with multiple devices (which indeed predates the modern kind of "iGPU with passthrough for dGPU" setup), and a generic mechanism for letting programs communicate with device drivers.

The same might go for audio, for example, with `/dev/snd/pcm*` on Linux providing access to any number of sound cards, without there being any audio-related syscalls at all. A more visible example might be disks, as programs directly interact with `\\.\Harddisk2` or `/dev/sdc` to create disk partitions or to write an ISO to a USB stick.

(I'm not sure how macOS exposes GPUs specifically, but it is a Unix so it certainly has device files *in general*, which live under /dev just as on Linux.)

For the game programmer, it's all integrated into the overall graphics programming interface provided by the OS that the program is using, e.g. DirectX has its own methods while Vulkan has its own (vkPhysicalDevice) and OpenGL has (or maybe doesn't have) its own. The OS-specific details are somewhat abstracted away by DX/VK/GL and this includes device selection.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the answer that you found - the apps don't
decide on the GPU - the operating system does that,
or rather an installed software called
[Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec):

> A codec is a device or computer program that encodes or decodes a data stream or signal

These are programs that are automatically launched by the
operating system when the application starts playing a video,
selected according to the format that is supported by this codec.
The codec's function is to accept the video/audio
commands from the application and to execute them using
the CPU/GPU.
A codec may be able to use the GPU, or only the CPU,
or both.

If the operating system chooses the wrong codec, it's possible
to force the choice by *assigning* the program to a GPU
of high or low performance.

In Windows 11, this is done in
*Settings > System > Display > Graphics*.
You click then on the application in the list and select
*Options*. You may then choose between
"Power saving" and "High performance".
You would need in this case to have installed a codec that
supports your choice, as the operating system may
override this setting if there is no such codec installed.

Comment: Codecs do not apply to 3D graphics acceleration. For 3D graphics, applications use Vulkan, Direct3D or the like, which are not codecs.

Comment: @DanielB: For me these are part of the operating system (or invoked by the operating system as shared libraries). At the end of the chain it's the codec that does the decoding.

Comment: Why downvote a correct answer ? Everything depends on the installed codecs. Apps can chose, but usually it's the OS or its video components that choose the codec.

Comment: The codec does the encoding and/or decoding, and can use either the CPU or GPU.